# Python setuptools symlinks and custom install extension

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging

I would like to achieve both of the following for my python package that has a setup.py and uses setuptools:

1. allow for installation with symlinks rather than copying package
   files
2. allow for custom code to run when "install" is used with
   setup.py

For the first, I usually do pip this way:

```
pip install -e . --user
```

and it works fine.

For the second, I do in setup.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function                                                                                                                
from setuptools import setup                                                                                                                         
from setuptools.command.install import install                                                                                                       
import os                                                                                                                                            


class CustomInstallCommand(install):                                                                                                                 
    def run(self):                                                                                                                                   
        print ("Custom code here")                                                                                                  
        install.run(self)                                                                                                                            

setup(...,
packages=['package_name'],                                                                                                                         
      package_dir={'package_name':'package_name'},                                                                                                           
      cmdclass={'install': CustomInstallCommand},                                                                                                    
      zip_safe=False)
```

However, I find that:

1. If I run pip as above, the custom code is never called
2. The custom code does run if I do:

   python setup.py install --user

but I'm not sure how to use this command with the equivalent `-e` option such that symlinks are installed instead of copies of files. How can I achieve both of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `install` won't be called. There are two modes available:

- "real" installation mode is invoked via `python setup.py install` and will copy the sources,
- the "development" mode is invoked via `python setup.py develop` and will only create symlinks to sources.

So you will have to override the `develop` command same way you do it with the `install` already:

```
from setuptools.command.develop import develop

...

class CustomDevInstallCommand(develop):
    def run(self):
        print('running custom develop command')
        super(CustomDevInstallCommand, self).run()


setup(
    ...,
    cmdclass={
        'install': CustomInstallCommand,
        'develop': CustomDevInstallCommand,
    },
)
```

Installing via `pip install --editable .` yields:

```
$ pip install --editable . -v
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/_y/2qk6029j4c7bwv0ddk3p96r00000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-1yw7baz2
...
Installing collected packages: spam
  Running setup.py develop for spam
    Running command python -c "import setuptools"
    Running command /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-49326214/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps
    running develop
    running custom develop command
    running egg_info
...
Successfully installed spam
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!